# No mountable file system Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystems, mount

I want to make USB bootable, but I am getting following error as I click **OSX-Mavericks.dmg**

[image]

How can I solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to download/re-create the image again. It's corrupted.

Comment: hahahaha , any other way , as this is huge file, and I can't waste time again. Any other suggestion?